# PrintWriter not working properly(?)

Tags: java, printing

So I wrote the following class to save the current state of a chess game which I am writing for my APCS final. According to everything which I have read, this *should* work, but it does not. The most that I have gotten it to print is "ro00\n". I have tried multiple variations on this code. I have defined write as a binary writer as a BoldWriter(no the right name); I have tried with and without flushes. But this is the most successful version of the class. If someone sees something which I have missed, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class SaveListener implements ActionListener {
        String temp;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(">saveInitiated");
       try {write = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                  new FileOutputStream("Board.txt"), "utf-8"));
               /*write = new PrintWriter(new File("Board.txt"), "UTF-8");*/
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y ++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    System.out.printf(">>y:%d,x:%d\n", y, x);
                    if (Board[y][x] != null) {
                        temp = Board[y][x].getType();
                        switch (temp) {
                            case "pawn":{write.print("pa");}
                            break;
                            case "rook": write.print("ro");
                            break;
                            case "knight": write.print("kn");
                            break;
                            case "bishop": write.print("bi");
                            break;
                            case "queen": write.print("qu");
                            break;
                            case "king": write.print("ki");
                        }
                        write.flush();
                        write.print(y);
                        write.flush();
                        write.print(x + "\n");
                        write.flush();
                    }
                    else write.print("nu\n");
                    write.close();
                }
            }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {System.out.println(">>FileNotFound!");} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {System.out.println(">>unsupportedEncodingException");}
            System.out.println(">saveConcluded");
        }
    }
```

I have a similar save block in a different chess program, which works perfectly.

```
if (save) {
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("Board.txt", "UTF-8");
            for (int y = 0; y < board.length; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < board[y].length; x++) {
                    write.print(board[y][x] + " ");
                }
            }
            write.close();
            System.out.println("Saved");
            save = false;
        }
```

By the way, the text I expect to see in the file is "ro00\n kn01\n bi02\n ki03\n qu04\n bi05\n kn06\n ro07\n pa00\n pa01\n pa02\n pa03\n pa04\n pa05\n pa06\n pa07\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n nu\n pa60\n pa61\n pa62\n pa63\n pa64\n pa65\n pa66\n pa67\n ro70\n kn71\n bi72\n ki73\n qu74\n bi75\n kn76\n ro77\". (spaces inserted for readability)

Comment: Are your printf's succeeding? It's possible Board[y][x] != null is failing, thus nothing is written. On a simplicity/readability note, why not output the full piece name? OR if you insist on the current method, just output the first 2 chars of getType() since that's all your switch does anyway and it isn't any worse than fixed string comparisons...

Comment: Have you tried to do a `printf` of `temp`? Is it always one of the values you expect? You could consider add a `default` to the switch: `throw new AssertionError("don't know how to serialize " + temp);`.

Answer (score 2):

```
}
else write.print("nu\n");
write.close();
```

This `else` block has no braces, so it only applies to the next statement, which is `write.print("nu\n");`. Then the writer is closed regardless of whether the board square was null, which is why nothing else is written. There's no reason to close the writer early, anyway. Try this:

```
} else {
    write.print("nu\n");
    write.flush();
}
```

Comment: OI! Thank you so much. Sometimes it really helps to have someone else read your work.